# Setting an array element with a sequence while training nn in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, keras-layer

I'm getting the error 
"Setting an array element with sequence" error while training my neural net in keras.

My input xtrain[0] is (1,300) and is of a list.
It's a vector of sentence formed using w2v.
I've tried changing it to numpy array and reshaped yet no help.
I used a flatten layer after my first dense layer, but landed on the error flatten requires input in 3 dimension.

I've googled through almost all the threads. Help me out !!

Dataset with sentences and labels.
I converted each sentence by finding the mean of individual tokens.
One hot encoded the labels.
Passed both into the fit method of two layers of neural network.
The elements of xtrain is of a list of length (300)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder,MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

data = pd.read_csv('dialog.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')

x = data.Dialogs #List of sentences
y = data.Label 

# To find the vectors of sentence using w2v
def meanv(coords):
    # assumes every item in coords has same length as item 0
    sumv = [0] * len(coords[0])
    for item in coords:
        for i in range(len(item)):
            sumv[i] += item[i]
    mean = [0] * len(sumv)
    for i in range(len(sumv)):
        mean[i] = float(sumv[i]) / len(coords)
    return mean

def sentvec(s):
    print(s)
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        sent = nlp(s[i])
        x[i] = meanv([w.vector for w in sent])

sentvec(x)

# To change the list vector to array
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    x[i] = np.array(x[i])


enc = LabelEncoder()
y = enc.fit_transform(y)
y = to_categorical(y)

input_dim = len(data.columns) - 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = input_dim , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))

opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = opt , metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'] )


model.fit(x,y, epochs = 100, batch_size = 10)

scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

pred1 = model.predict_classes(test_x)
pred = model.predict(test_x)
```

Comment: This is a numpy error, not a keras once, but anyways, you should add full code and tracebacks in order to help you.

Comment: I got a similar error a few mins ago when I passed a tensor to an API that expected a numpy array. In my case I was trying to do K.set_value(tensorA, tensorB) which is incorrect; (K.update(tensor, tensor) is correct). It is likely that this is a situation caused by incorrectly mixing tensors and numpy arrays.

Comment: My code is a very simple one. Dataset with sentences and labels.
I converted each sentence by finding the mean of individual tokens.
One hot encoded the labels.
Passed both into the fit method of two layers of neural network.
The elements of xtrain is of a list of length (300)

Comment: kindly add the error (stack trace-back) of your code. So will be able to see in which line you are getting error.

Comment: Hi. I have added the code. Help me out